# 9 slice scaling in Sprite Kit

Tags: sprite-kit, scaling

Does Sprite Kit have an equivalent to 9 slice scaling for sprites?

I have tried googling, but not finding anything, but... it's often a feature that goes by different names in different frameworks. So I could be missing it.

Comment: Not part of the SK framework.

Comment: It looks as though it is... via contortions of a property called centerRect, to only cover the part of the sprite to be stretched in 2 dimensions, whilst the corresponding up and lower sections are scaled horizontally, the side sections vertically, and the 4 corners outside that centerRect area are not scaled. Messy, and unbelievably badly named, but seems to be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpriteKit supports 9-slices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW10

The document doesn't tell you to set the size which won't work without it, so here it is:

```
SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"stretchable_button.png"];
button.centerRect = CGRectMake(12.0/28.0, 12.0/28.0, 4.0/28.0, 4.0/28.0);
button.size = CGSizeMake(100.0, 50.0);
```